# Spring SseEmitter behaves differently when wrapped in ResponseEntity

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, openapi

I have the following spring-boot rest endpoints (details omitted):

```
@GetMapping(path=/stream1)
public SseEmitter stream1() {
  return new SseEmitter();
}

@GetMapping(path=/stream2)
public ResponseEntity<Object> stream2() {
  return ResponseEntity.ok().contentType(MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM).body(new SseEmitter());
}
```

The method that returns the SseEmitter works as expected but stream2 produces a 500 result and throws the following error:

```
DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved HttpMessageNotWritableException: No
converter for [SseEmitter] with preset Content-Type 'null'
```

Even if i explicitly set the content-type i get a 500.

From the spring-boot docs the `SseEmitter` should work when returned directly or as part of a `ResponseEntity`. I need to return a ResponseEntity to get this to work with OpenApi generated code.

What am i missing to get this to work?